# How do I loop across specific ranges with the row number as the variable?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have a bunch of formulae that is meant for specific (non-contiguous) ranges in my data. Is there any way to do this in less lines with an array and/or a loop?

```
.Range("R" & RowA).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]"
.Range("W" & RowA).FormulaR1C1 = "=(RC[-5]*RC[-7])+RC[-2]"
.Range("Y" & RowA).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-12]*RC[-2]"

.Range("R" & RowB).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]"
.Range("W" & RowB).FormulaR1C1 = "=(RC[-5]*RC[-7])+RC[-2]"
.Range("Y" & RowB).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-12]*RC[-2]"

.Range("R" & RowC).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]"
.Range("W" & RowC).FormulaR1C1 = "=(RC[-5]*RC[-7])+RC[-2]"
.Range("Y" & RowC).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-12]*RC[-2]"
```

Comment: `.Range("R" & RowA & ",R" & RowB & ",R" & RowC).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]"` should work if you have a limited number of rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, although I suspect not quite in the way you're thinking. Use an array instead of separate variables `RowA`, `RowB` and `RowC`, so you'd replace

```
Dim RowA as Long, RowB as Long, RowC as Long
RowA = 1
RowB = 3
RowC = 7 'example figures
```

With -

```
Dim Row(1 to 3) as Long
Row(1) = 1
Row(2) = 3
Row(3) = 7
```

Then your above code can be shortened to the following loop:

```
For a = Lbound(Row) to Ubound(Row)
    .Range("R" & Row(a)).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]"
    .Range("W" & Row(a)).FormulaR1C1 = "=(RC[-5]*RC[-7])+RC[-2]"
    .Range("Y" & Row(a)).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-12]*RC[-2]"
Next
```

Comment: is there a way that I can use less generic variable names in the array? For example, CustomerARow, CustomerBRow, etc. This is because I would also need to refer to these variables later on as well.

Comment: @OliverTheseira you can name the array whatever you like (for your above example I'd suggest calling it `CustomerRow(1 to 3)` )- however within the brackets it has to be just whole numbers. However you can use whatever whole numbers you wish, e.g. an array using the number 15 to 17 instead of 1 to 3, if that helps at all.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I was on block leave. Thank you @Spencer, this works perfectly. However, the shortcoming of declaring variable arrays would be that the variable identifiers would only be limited to integers as opposed to the customer names in this scenario.

Answer (score 3):

I would store the rows in an array, then use `Union` to collect all the rows in a variable and `Intersect` that with each column.

This way you can access all defined rows of a specific column at once.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub example()
    Dim RowArr() As Variant
    RowArr = Array(1, 3, 17) 'define your rows here
    
    Dim AllRows As Range
        
    With ActiveSheet
        Dim Row As Variant
        For Each Row In RowArr
            If AllRows Is Nothing Then
                Set AllRows = .Rows(Row)
            Else
                Set AllRows = Union(AllRows, .Rows(Row))
            End If
        Next Row
        
        'write in all rows of a specific column
        Intersect(.Columns("R"), AllRows).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]"
        Intersect(.Columns("W"), AllRows).FormulaR1C1 = "=(RC[-5]*RC[-7])+RC[-2]"
        Intersect(.Columns("Y"), AllRows).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-12]*RC[-2]"
    End With
End Sub
```

Instead of the loop you can also write:

```
Set AllRows = .Range("1:1,3:3,17:17")
```

like

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub example()
    With ActiveSheet
        Dim AllRows As Range
        Set AllRows = .Range("1:1,3:3,17:17")
        
        'write in all rows of a specific column
        Intersect(.Columns("R"), AllRows).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]"
        Intersect(.Columns("W"), AllRows).FormulaR1C1 = "=(RC[-5]*RC[-7])+RC[-2]"
        Intersect(.Columns("Y"), AllRows).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-12]*RC[-2]"
    End With
End Sub
```

but this works only for a smaller amount of rows. If you have more you need to use `Union`

Comment: That's a nice way, haven't seen that before. Thanks for answering too.

Comment: @Capt.Krusty Advantage here is that you have only 3 write processes (instead of 9) because you write all rows in a column at once! And the amount of write processes is the time critic factor, the less you have the faster your code is.

Comment: Hi @Pᴇʜ, if I use the Array function as what you've done here, would I be able to write `RowArr = Array(CustA, CustB, CustC)`? If so, this would actually be a better solution for me as I can intuitively store a variable with an identifier for each customer, as opposed to purely integers.

Comment: @OliverTheseira I would not hardcode variables for `CustA` and so on. What if you add a customer and then you have to touch your code again? No, instead make your code more dynamic so you don't need to touch it if there is one customer added. Whenever you have the feeling you need to number (or ABC) your variable names this is a clear sign you are doing something wrong. • I cannot give you a more detailed answer in a comment so I suggest you open up a new question for that and explain with a good example what you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```vb
Sub Test()
Dim letters, rows, i, letter, row

letters = Array("R", "W", "Y")
rows = Array(1, 5, 17)          'RowA, RowB, and so on...
i = 0
j = 0
For Each row In rows
    For Each letter In letters
        Debug.Print letters(i) & rows(j)
    '    .Range(letters(i) & rows(i)).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]"
    '    .Range(letters(i) & rows(i)).FormulaR1C1 = "=(RC[-5]*RC[-7])+RC[-2]"
    '    .Range(letters(i) & rows(i)).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-12]*RC[-2]"
         
        i = i + 1
    Next letter
    j = j + 1
    i = 0
Next row

End Sub
```

Comment: Good idea storing 'Letters' as an array, but not sure it's actually going to improve the efficiency given that a different action is applied for each letter?

Comment: For knowledge purposes, may I know what each variable's type is? I am not clear on array variable types. Would it be right to declare letters and letter as string and rows and row as long variable types?

Comment: Thanks @Spencer Barnes. It should just show the possibilities with For-Each-Loops as he asked for "specific (non-contiguous) ranges". The changing of the i and j characters is mere work. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @ Oliver Thereisa: You can define the arrays as 'Variant' and i, j as 'Integer'.

Comment: @Capt.Krusty may I know why you need to write i=0 at the bottom?

Comment: I thought you wanted to do all the operations on all "rows", therefore you would have needed to "reset" the row counter.

Comment: @Capt.Krusty, I am still trying to improve my understanding on this as I am working on a similar question at the same time [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68661949/why-does-my-for-each-loop-skip-over-some-items-in-my-array/68663705#68663705] - why do you choose to use a For Each loop instead of a For loop? With a For loop, you wouldn't need to explicitly iterate your i and j values, which seems like additional steps to me. Is my understanding correct? You may refer to Spencer's answer above for an idea of what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 2):

### Using 'Helper' Procedures

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub UsingRefRows()
    
    Const RowA As Long = 1
    Const RowB As Long = 3
    Const RowC As Long = 5
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheet1
    
    Dim rrg As Range: Set rrg = RefRows(ws, RowA, RowB, RowC)
    
    Intersect(rrg, ws.Columns("R")).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]"
    Intersect(rrg, ws.Columns("W")).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-5]*RC[-7]+RC[-2]"
    Intersect(rrg, ws.Columns("Y")).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-12]*RC[-2]"

End Sub

Sub UsingRefRowsAndWriteRowsR1C1()
    
    Const RowA As Long = 1
    Const RowB As Long = 3
    Const RowC As Long = 5
    
    Const ColumnsList As String = "R,W,Y"
    Const FormulasList As String _
        = "=RC[-1]" & "," _
        & "=RC[-5]*RC[-7]+RC[-2]" & "," _
        & "=RC[-12]*RC[-2]"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheet1
    
    Dim rrg As Range: Set rrg = RefRows(ws, RowA, RowB, RowC)
    
    WriteRowsR1C1 rrg, ColumnsList, FormulasList
    
End Sub


Function RefRows( _
    ByVal ws As Worksheet, _
    ParamArray DataRows() As Variant) _
As Range
    Dim rg As Range
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 0 To UBound(DataRows)
        If rg Is Nothing Then
            Set rg = ws.Rows(DataRows(n))
        Else
            Set rg = Union(rg, ws.Rows(DataRows(n)))
        End If
    Next n
    If Not rg Is Nothing Then
        Set RefRows = rg
    End If
End Function

Sub WriteRowsR1C1( _
        ByVal RowsRange As Range, _
        ByVal ColumnsList As String, _
        ByVal FormulasList As String)
    
    Dim Cols() As String: Cols = Split(ColumnsList, ",")
    Dim Formulas() As String: Formulas = Split(FormulasList, ",")
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = RowsRange.Worksheet
    
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 0 To UBound(Cols)
        Intersect(RowsRange, ws.Columns(Cols(n))).FormulaR1C1 = Formulas(n)
    Next n
    
End Sub
```