# Why does my For Each loop skip over some items in my array?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops, foreach

My full code is as below:

```
FirstRow = Columns("B").Find("B").MergeArea.Row
LastRow = Columns("B").Find("B").MergeArea.Row + Columns("B").Find("B").MergeArea.Rows.Count - 1

FirstRow2 = Columns("B").Find("N").MergeArea.Row
LastRow2 = Columns("B").Find("N").MergeArea.Row + Columns("B").Find("N").MergeArea.Rows.Count - 1

Range("A" & LastRow + 1).EntireRow.Insert
Range("A" & LastRow2 + 2).EntireRow.Insert

Range("Q" & LastRow + 1) = 50
Range("Q" & LastRow2 + 2) = 100

Dim Col, ColArr, CalcRow, CalcRowArr, FRow, FirstRowArr, LRow, LastRowArr
ColArr = Array("R", "W", "Y")
CalcRowArr = Array(LastRow + 1, LastRow2 + 2)
FirstRowArr = Array(FirstRow, FirstRow2 + 1)
LastRowArr = Array(LastRow, LastRow2 + 1)

For Each Col In ColArr
For Each CalcRow In CalcRowArr
For Each FRow In FirstRowArr
For Each LRow In LastRowArr

Range(Col & CalcRow).Formula = "=SUM(" & Col & FRow & ":" & Col & LRow & ")"

Next LRow
Next FRow
Next CalcRow
Next Col
```

Basically I am trying to convert these 6 lines of code:

```
Range("R" & LastRow + 1).Formula = "=SUM(R" & FirstRow & ":R" & LastRow & ")"
Range("W" & LastRow + 1).Formula = "=SUM(W" & FirstRow & ":W" & LastRow & ")"
Range("Y" & LastRow + 1).Formula = "=SUM(Y" & FirstRow & ":Y" & LastRow & ")"

Range("R" & LastRow2 + 2).Formula = "=SUM(R" & FirstRow2 + 1 & ":R" & LastRow2 + 1 & ")"
Range("W" & LastRow2 + 2).Formula = "=SUM(W" & FirstRow2 + 1 & ":W" & LastRow2 + 1 & ")"
Range("Y" & LastRow2 + 2).Formula = "=SUM(Y" & FirstRow2 + 1 & ":Y" & LastRow2 + 1 & ")"
```

into the array loop in my code above:

```
Dim Col, ColArr, CalcRow, CalcRowArr, FRow, FirstRowArr, LRow, LastRowArr
ColArr = Array("R", "W", "Y")
CalcRowArr = Array(LastRow + 1, LastRow2 + 2)
FirstRowArr = Array(FirstRow, FirstRow2 + 1)
LastRowArr = Array(LastRow, LastRow2 + 1)

For Each Col In ColArr
For Each CalcRow In CalcRowArr
For Each FRow In FirstRowArr
For Each LRow In LastRowArr

Range(Col & CalcRow).Formula = "=SUM(" & Col & FRow & ":" & Col & LRow & ")"

Next LRow
Next FRow
Next CalcRow
Next Col
```

However, my end result is skipping over the first items (FirstRow and LastRow) in FirstRowArr and LastRowArr respectively, meaning that my first set of 3 values ("R", "W", "Y" & LastRow + 1) becomes a duplicate of my second set of 3 values ("R", "W", "Y" & LastRow2 + 2).

Comment: If you do not show us how `LastRow`,`LastRow2`, `firstRow` etc. it is difficult to understand where your problem is.

Comment: I think your logic is wrong with the last two loops, as you are overwriting the formula in the same `Range(Col & CalcRow)` each time.

Comment: I've included my full code above. @Rory, how should I go about it to avert overwriting the formula?

Comment: The whole thing seems unnecessarily complicated, but I think you just want the one `For Each col` loop and then a `For n = lbound(calcrowarr) to ubound(calcrowarr): range(col & calcrow(n)).formula = "=SUM(" & Col & FirstRowArr(n) & ":" & Col & LastRowArr(n) & ")": next n`

Comment: @Rory, how does FirstRowArr(n) and LastRowArr(n) get called? My understanding is that the index n in this case is bound to the items in CalcRowArr - LastRow + 1, LastRow2 + 2

Comment: No, the index is just a number. It's a `For` loop, not a `For Each`.

Comment: @Rory, your solution worked but calcrow(n) needs to be changed to calcrowarr(n). Can you post your solution as an answer so that I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my earlier comment, you only really want two loops:

```
For Each Col In ColArr
   Dim n as long
   For n = lbound(calcrowarr) to ubound(calcrowarr)
      range(col & calcrowarr(n)).formula = "=SUM(" & Col & FirstRowArr(n) & ":" & Col & LastRowArr(n) & ")"
   next n
Next Col
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. May I know how you know when to use a For loop and when to use a For Each loop?

Comment: @OliverTheseira it depends entirely on the situation. `For Each` is generally faster for looping collections, but if you need to loop through the corresponding items in two collections, you probably want a For loop with one or more counter variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this .. Edited your code a little. Instead of arrays and loops you can insert the formula in 4 lines starting from `CR = LR + 1` using relative referenced formula (R1C1)

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim FR, LR, FR2, LR2, CR, CR2
FR = Columns("B").Find("B").MergeArea.Row
LR = Columns("B").Find("B").MergeArea.Row + _
    Columns("B").Find("B").MergeArea.Rows.Count - 1

FR2 = Columns("B").Find("N").MergeArea.Row
LR2 = Columns("B").Find("N").MergeArea.Row + _
    Columns("B").Find("N").MergeArea.Rows.Count - 1

Range("A" & LR + 1).EntireRow.Insert
Range("A" & LR2 + 2).EntireRow.Insert

Range("Q" & LR + 1) = 50
Range("Q" & LR2 + 2) = 100

CR = LR + 1
Range("R" & CR & ",W" & CR & ",Y" & CR).FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=SUM(R[" & FR - CR & "]C:R[" & LR - CR & "]C)"
CR2 = LR2 + 2
Range("R" & CR2 & ",W" & CR2 & ",Y" & CR2).FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=SUM(R[" & FR2 - CR2 & "]C:R[" & LR2 - CR2 & "]C)"

End Sub
```

**Edit** .. Added as per comment below.

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim findArr, FR, LR, CR, i As Long
findArr = Array("B", "N") 'Zero based array

For i = LBound(findArr) To UBound(findArr)

    FR = Columns("B").Find(findArr(i)).MergeArea.Row
    LR = Columns("B").Find(findArr(i)).MergeArea.Row + _
        Columns("B").Find(findArr(i)).MergeArea.Rows.Count - 1
    
    Range("A" & LR + 1).EntireRow.Insert
    Range("Q" & LR + 1) = 50 * (i + 1)
    
    CR = LR + 1
    Range("R" & CR & ",W" & CR & ",Y" & CR).FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUM(R[" & FR - CR & "]C:R[" & LR - CR & "]C)"

Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Please check `FR - CR` etc in the formula. You may have to adjust it by -/+1. .. If you still want a loop to make it flexible to accommodate, more mergerareas, then I you suggest, loop through each mergearea right from the beginning instead of adding more variables like FR2 and LR2 and CR2. There also, you can use relative referencing to enter formula in all columns at once in each loop.

Comment: If you decide to loop through each mergearea from the beginning, you will need only one array, array of values to be found `{"B","N"}`. Everything else can be made dynamic with variables.